# How to make x-callback-url call to local app in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, x-callback-url

I have a local app (NotePlan) installed on macOS, and it publishes an [x-callback-url scheme](https://noteplan.co/faq/General/X-Callback-Url%20Scheme/). I'm simply trying to call it from a ruby script, but can't find help on this. (Plenty of help available for HTTP calls, but this is to a *local* app.)

```rb
require 'open-uri'
title = "note title"
uri = "noteplan://x-callback-url/openNote?noteTitle=#{title}"
uriEncoded = URI.escape(uri)
response = open(uriEncoded).read
```

It returns this error:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - noteplan://x-callback-url/openNote?noteTitle=note%20title (Errno::ENOENT)
```

From the command line calling `open "noteplan://x-callback-url/openNote?noteTitle=note%20title"` does the expected thing, so the basic mechanism appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found a way, though I regard it a hack, not a good answer.

`response = %x[open "#{uri}"]`

i.e. call the `open` command in a new shell.

I still hope someone can provide a better answer.